# Como criar uma tarefa agenda com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Galera estou tentando trabalhando com cron pela primeira vez e tentando criar uma tarefa agendada bem simples.

estava olhando o documentação e vi que este comando precisa ser executado

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

executei ele no terminal assim:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/mail-with-cron schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

com o diretorio do meu projeto e depois dei um `php artisan serve`

mas ele não executou o comando de inspire

Comment: Como esta o arquivo mail-with-cron/app/console/Kernel.php dentro?

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é um comando que é executado no terminal. Você precisa colocar esse comando no cron do seu server. Para isso execute no terminal `crontab -e`

Será aberto um arquivo. Aqui sim você coloca a definição do crontab.

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Isso irá executar todos os comandos definidos no método `schedule` em `app/Console/Kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->hourly();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Faltou o artisan no final do diretorio, então fica assim:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/mail-with-cron/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Não é um comando esse cron